# Auth::check() logout user in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, authentication

When I want to login the user after they registered I use the following code:

```
Auth::login($user);
Auth::check();
```

If I remove the second line the user can successfully login but if I add it they can't.

Comment: Auth::check() doesn't logout user, only checks if a user is authenticated.
The problem is outside the code you have provided. Maybe the value of $user is wrong type.

Comment: when remove line two its ok @NikolaiKiselev

Comment: Share the entire file please, most probably the issue is outside those two lines of code.